# IsDefaultEntityContainer in OData metadata

Tags: odata, odatalib

When I generate my EdmModel using Microsoft.Data.OData.dll, v5.6.1.0 as follows:

```
var eModel = new Microsoft.Data.Edm.Library.EdmModel();
var container = new EdmEntityContainer("namespace...", "container1");
var eRowType = ...;
eModel.AddElement(eRowType);
var eSet = container.AddEntitySet("...", eRowType);
eModel.AddElement(container);
```

and then generate the metadata with

```
ODataMessageWriter payloadWriter = new ODataMessageWriter(payloadResponse, settings, eModel);
payloadWriter.WriteMetadataDocument();
```

I get xml that does not have `IsDefaultEntityContainer="true"`.
Some OData libraries require that attribute. 
How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the SetIsDefaultEntityContainer() method:

eModel.AddElement(container);

eModel.SetIsDefaultEntityContainer(container, true);